# Tagger Related Entries URLs With Structure

Tags: structure

I have two structure listings channels called blog and articles. The content can relate between the two channels.

How can I get the correct page url inside the related content tag? Structure's {page_url} doesn't work.

This is the current code:

```
{exp:tagger:entries tag="{segment_2}" custom_fields="article_content" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
<h3><a href="{site_url}articles/{tagger:entry_url_title}">{tagger:entry_title}</a></h3>
{/exp:tagger:entries}
```

Basically I want the articles part of the url to dynamically change to either articles or blog based on Structure's url hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to EE 2.6.1, there was an EE bug with page_url: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-1

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for your reply. Should {page_url} work inside a {exp:tagger:entries} field anyway, even with the bug fix? Even on their docs example they have the first part of the URL hardcoded like above.

I know you're not with DevDemon by the way! I can ask them if you're not sure.